# How do you create a random 64 bit number?

Tags: c#, random, 64-bit, int

I have part of a spec that requires me to create a random 64 bit number with the following converted to a character string :
(0 to 2^63 - 1)

I have no idea what this means in the brackets, can anyone help?

Comment: What programming language, platform, environment, etc ?

Comment: OK - I've already posted a C answer below which should be quite trivial to port to C#.

Answer (score 2):

The parenthesis is set-builder notation for a random 64 bit number between 0 and 2^63-1, not including 0 nor 2^63-1.

Comment: I don't think it's set notation - it just means the full *positive* range of a 64 bit 2's complement signed int, i.e. 0 to 2^63 - 1 inclusive.

Comment: Maybe.  OP did mention brackets, so maybe op meant [0, 2^63-1]?

Comment: Most common RNGs generate positive values so typically a 32 bit RNG generates values from 0..2^31-1 (i.e. the negative half of the 32 bit int range is not used), and so it seems likely that if you are specifying a 64 bit RNG it would have an output range of 0..2^63-1. But this is just guess-work of course...

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify a programming language I'll give a solution in C and then you can adapt it to whatever programming language you might be using if it turns out not to be C (or a close relative).

You can just call [arc4random](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/arc4random/) twice and concatenate the values:

```
 #include <stdint.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int64_t rand64(void)
 {
     uint64_t r_lo = (uint64_t)arc4random();
     uint64_t r_hi = (uint64_t)arc4random();
     return (int64_t)((r_hi << 31) | (r_low >> 1));
 }
```

You can convert this to a hex ASCII string quite easily:

```
 char s[17];

 int64_t r = rand64();
 sprintf(s, "%16llx", r);
```

(If you need it as decimal or some other format then just modify the `sprintf` format string accordingly).